# Android studio API33 crashes computer

Tags: android-studio

I am using studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1 with as far i can find all updates installed.
When i am starting an emulator with API 33 on it my computer goes into a reboot.
No warning, no error. If Device screen opens (i have it detached) it starts the load and then out of nothing a reboot.

This happen when i try just to start the emulator. i am not clicking on the run-app button.

I do not even have a clue where to start the search.

Comment: Maybe [create a bug report](https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs) which then appears in the [Android Studio issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192708&s=modified_time:descfirst&pli=1).

Comment: Thank yo Markus. filed a report with Google
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/259639684

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this also for Google was no easy one but they did found the problem.
All emulator with a API 29 or higher rebotted by PC.
In the end it was the HAXM
The HAXM installer was not installed in the SDK Manager->SDK Tools.
After intalling it the emulator works.

See the issuetracker for the full story
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/259639684